# Add a column value based on selection of a subset of rows

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like below, which was read in from impala table. I am trying to add columns based on the sql queries. For example, I'd like to add a new column `ConditionAB` , with this query `select * from df where ConditionA = Y and ConditionB = N`, for the rows in result, `ConditionAB` column value should be Y, and the rest of the rows in the df should have value N (see the sample output ). Could you please help shed some light on this? I have several sql queries as conditions, and hope to have one df as result. Any method ie Pyspark api, or Spark sql would be fine, preferable sql. Thank you.

Input:

```
    customerNo  ConditionA    ConditionB     ConditionC   ConditionD
       1          Y                 Y            Y             N
       2          N                 N            Y             Y
       3          Y                 Y            N             N
       4          Y                 N            Y             Y
       5          Y                 N            Y             Y
```

output:

```
    customerNo  ConditionA    ConditionB     ConditionC   ConditionD.   ConditionAB
       1          Y                 Y            Y             N            N
       2          N                 N            Y             Y            N
       3          Y                 Y            N             N            N
       4          Y                 N            Y             Y            Y 
       5          Y                 N            Y             Y            Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the cue from @Sivakumar's answer, in pyspark you can write

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn('ConditionAB', F.when((F.col('ConditionA') == 'Y') & (F.col('ConditionB') == 'N'), 'Y').otherwise('N'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet and it's implemented using Scala, you can re-use the same logic for python

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df
.withColumn("ConditionAB", when(col("ConditionA") === "Y" && col("ConditionB") === "N"), "Y").otherwise("N"))
```